# How can I create bootstrap carousel dynamically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to build carousel dynamically. 
here is my html code

```
<div id="mycarousel">
</div>
```

in javascript i am doing this;

```
var data='';
data='<div id="relatedItemCarousel"  class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000"  >';
        data=data+'<div class="carousel-inner" id="relatedItemCraousel1">'; 
//caraousel content
data='</div>'
data=data+'<a class="left carousel-control" id="related-item-carousel-control-left" href="#relatedItemCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" >'+
        '<i class="ion-ios-arrow-back size-32" ></i></a>'+            
    '<a class="right carousel-control" id="related-item-carousel-control-right" href="#relatedItemCaraousel" role="button" data-slide="next" >'+
        '<i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward size-32" ></i>'+
    '</a></div>';
  $('#mycarousel').html(data);
```

But it is not showing anything on page. Do I need to refresh carousel again?

Answer (score 1):

`$('mycarousel').html(data);` should be `$('#mycarousel').html(data);`.

`#` is id selector in jQuery.

Comment: sorry i pasted incorrectly . I used #id selector only . what would be the solution ?

Comment: Your code works. Here, I've tidied it up:  [https://jsfiddle.net/moonlife/0pz5sd9g/](https://jsfiddle.net/moonlife/0pz5sd9g/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are assuming that we have an array of images:

So first of all we need to create a empty container in which slides will be inserted dynamically.

Add Below HTML code to conatiner where you want to append this.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**In above html code below are points to understand:**

Class carousel inner is empty, there is where you gonna place your images for then carousel.

Class carousel-indicatiors is also empty, will be filled by JS.

Once you have added the html code **insert below JavaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  for(var i=0 ; i< imageCollection.length ; i++) {
    $('<div class="item"><img src="'+imageCollection[i]+'"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
    $('<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')

  }
  $('.item').first().addClass('active');
  $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel();
});
```

In above code **imageCollection** is basically the collection of image urls which you want to display in the carousel panel.

Basically, you append all your images to class carousel-inner, you add carousel control li's, then you add the active class to the first image and to the first carousel indicator li., and finally, you initialize your carousel.

**Note** that all this is inside a document ready function, but you can this anywhere you want.

Hope this will help you  :)

Comment: Similar issue to this:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177572/add-slides-to-bootstrap3-carousal-dynamically-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Well, Bootstrap Carousel has various parameters to control.

i.e.

**Interval:** Specifies the delay (in milliseconds) between each slide.

**pause:** Pauses the carousel from going through the next slide when the mouse pointer enters the carousel, and resumes the sliding when the mouse pointer leaves the carousel.

**wrap:** Specifies whether the carousel should go through all slides continuously, or stop at the last slide

For your reference:

[image]

Fore more details please [click here...](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)

Hope this will help you :)

**Note:** this is for the further help.. I mean how can you customise or change default behaviour once carousel is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same problem and came up with this sort of kludgy solution.

Javascript:

```
function carouselMaker(myCarouselName, picArray){

<!-------------------- carousel indicators -------------------->
  var indicatorInnerHtml= "";
  for(var i=0 ; i< picArray.length ; i++) 
  {
      if(i==0){
        indicatorInnerHtml += "<li data-target=\"#"+myCarouselName+"\" data-slide-to=\"" + i +"\" class=\"active\"> </li>"; 
      }
      else{
        indicatorInnerHtml += "<li data-target=\"#"+myCarouselName+"\" data-slide-to=\"" + i +"\" class=\"\"> </li>"; 
      }       
  }  
  var indicatorsHtml = "<ol class=\"carousel-indicators\">" + indicatorInnerHtml + " </ol>";

<!---------------- carousel-inner --------------------------->
  var slidesInnerHtml = "";
  for(var i=0 ; i< picArray.length ; i++) 
  { 
      if(i==0){
        slidesInnerHtml += "<div class=\"item active\"><img src=\"" + picArray[i] + "\"><div class=\"carousel-caption\"></div>  </div>";
      }
      else{
        slidesInnerHtml += "<div class=\"item\"><img src=\"" + picArray[i] + "\"><div class=\"carousel-caption\"></div> </div>"; 
      }
  }  
  var slidesHtml = "<div class=\"carousel-inner\">" + slidesInnerHtml + "</div>";


<!---------------- carousel controls ----------------------->  
  var controlsHtml=  "" +
  "<a class=\"left carousel-control\" href=\"#" + myCarouselName + "\" data-slide=\"prev\">" + 
  "     <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span>" +
  "</a> " +

   "<a class=\"right carousel-control\" href=\"#" + myCarouselName + "\" data-slide=\"next\">" +
   "    <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>" +
   " </a> ";   

  var innerCarousel = indicatorsHtml + slidesHtml + controlsHtml;

  document.getElementById(myCarouselName).innerHTML = innerCarousel;      
}
```

And when I want to insert a carousel somewhere on my page I do this on my PHP page:

```
<?php
$carouselName = "testCarousel";
$carouselPicList = "\"".$pictureTwo."\" , \"".$pictureThree."\" , \"".$pictureFour."\"";
?>

<div  id="<?php echo $carouselName ?>"  class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        carouselMaker("<?php echo $carouselName ?>", [<?php echo $carouselPicList ?>]);
    </script>

</div>
```

Where `$pictureNumber` is the path of where my image is, i.e. `$pictureOne = "img/firstImage.jpg";`
This has the advantage of being able to create multiple carousels on the same page- something I wasn't able to find in any other example.

Can't help but feel the code is a bit hokey so if anyone has any suggestions I'd be glad to hear them.