# Dynamically adding photographs to bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have the problem in my code. I would like to dynamicaly add images to bootstrap carousel. First problem that I encounter is that all images are set to active. And second is that left and right navigation is not working. Thanks for answer.

Ajax callback:

```
  success: function (data) {
            $(data.ResponseData.Data.fileNames).each(function (index, imageName) {

                $("<div class='item active'><img src='/Images/IndexSlideShow/" + imageName + "' alt='Graduation Image'></div>").appendTo("#indexCarousel .carousel-inner");
                $("<li data-target='#indexCarousel' data-slide-to='" + index + "'></li>").appendTo('#indexCarousel .carousel-indicators');

                $('#indexCarousel .item').first().addClass('active');
                $('#indexCarousel .carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
                $('#indexCarousel').carousel();
            });
        },
```

This is HTML code:

```
<div id="indexCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#indexCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#indexCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Edit:

Comment: I don't believe Bootstrap Carousel accommodates dynamic insertion. You'll need to rebuild the carousel after adding elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add slides to Bootstrap3 Carousal dynamically using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177572/add-slides-to-bootstrap3-carousal-dynamically-using-jquery)

Comment: <div class='item active'> - I was adding all items as active, this was the problem. It was obviously my mistake

Comment: Very good. Please provide and accept an answer or delete your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class='item active'>
```

I was adding all items as active, this was the problem. It was obviously my mistake.

Comment: So what did you do instead of using `item active`? , Did you just use `active`or something else?