# Dynamically Adding images to Bootstrap Carousel in Rails 4 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, loops, carousel

I'm using Active Admin to upload images to my app, that is working fine. But I want the uploaded images to be displayed in a Bootstrap Carrousel. My lack of experience using Rails and Javascript limits me to get the result I want.

The Javascript console throws back this error :

```
carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:148 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined(…)
  Carousel.slide @ carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:148
  Carousel.next @ carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:110
  (anonymous function) @ carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:186
  each @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:371
  each @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:138
  Plugin @ carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:178
  clickHandler @ carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:218
  dispatch @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227
  elemData.handle @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879
```

**Edit**
I looked at the possible duplicate, I can see how this might be a possible duplicate, but I´m not sure on how I would integrate my Ruby `loop`into the `javascript`.

Can someone advise me please.  The code is below

**Edited** **Updated code**

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>                     
   <div class="item #{"active" if index.zero? }">
  <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large)) %>                    
   </div>
  <% end %>

   ...
  </div>

   <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
     <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 2000
   })
 </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add slides to Bootstrap 3 carousel dynamically using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177572/add-slides-to-bootstrap-3-carousel-dynamically-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will be missing the class 'active' or the class 'active' is added to all items. Add the class 'active' to the photo which you want to show first.

Below code will add the class 'active' to the first image.

```
<% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>                     
  <div class="item #{"active" if index.zero? }">
    <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large)) %>                    
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also please check for javascript errors on your page.

Comment: thanks, but its not working, I get this error in  the `JS console` : `carousel.self-e47323f….js?body=1:148 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined(…)`

Comment: Could you please check whether this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027830/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-with-bootstrap-carousel) helps you?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, the answer in the url suggest calling `active` but that is what the loop is doing. Maybe some of the other suggestions in  the `url`can work.