# Bootstrap Carousel is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm appending carousel image and title, it's working fine in chrome and Mozilla, but it's not working in ie.

```
slider_items += '<div class="item ">\ ' +
                                '<div class="crop-img">\ ' +
                            '<a class="slider-link-' + item + '" href="articles.php/' + slider_url_title_array[item] + '/' + slider_link_array[item] + '">\ ' +
                            '<img class="img img-responsive image-' + item + '" src="' + slider_image_src_array[item] + '" alt="article-image">\ ' +
                            '</a>\ ' +
                            '</div>\ ' +
                            '<div class="carousel-caption">\ ' +
                            '<h3 class="slider-title-' + item + '">' + slider_title_array[item] + '</h3>\ ' +
                            '</div>\ ' +
                            '</div>'
                    }
                    $('.carousel-inner').append(slider_items);
                     $('.carousel-inner .item:first-child').addClass('active');
```

Please help me to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: Which carousel. Are you using library or any custom code? Where is the carousel code? How do you initialize the carousel?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap Carousel, it's working fine, but i'm not getting image and tittle - which i'm appending

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177572/add-slides-to-bootstrap-3-carousel-dynamically-using-jquery

Comment: Are you getting any errors in `console` ? Please post those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add slides to Bootstrap 3 carousel dynamically using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177572/add-slides-to-bootstrap-3-carousel-dynamically-using-jquery)

Comment: Please provide any working sample fiddle/://codepen.io related to your code. so that we can help you soon.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, I'll try that

Comment: Hi shivkumar, if i'm using static code it's working fine in ie, but the problem is while i'm using dynamic data - (append html)

Comment: Now i'm getting this error in console - "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference"